# Unable to set full background image on ion-card ionic 4

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image: I want this to Cover the complete area]

I am trying to set Background image of an Ion-card which will completely cover the area of card but whenever I add background image it doesn't cover its complete area but It leaves the corner .My code is

```
   <ion-card class="design" style="width : 43%;height: 35%;">
   </ion-card>

    Scss Code
    .design  {
     background-image: url(../../assets/icon/rectangleCopy25@3x.png);
     background-size: cover;
     display: inline-block;

               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
#design{
            background-size: 100%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
            background-size: cover!important;
            width: 105vw!important;
            height: 100vh!important;
            margin-left: -10%!important;
            background-attachment: fixed!important;
            margin-top: -10%!important;
            background-position: center center!important;
          }
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-background-image-jmun8u?file=pages/home/home.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Simple:
You need to point your own component to define the style settings.

```
ion-card {
     background-image: url('assets / 35.jpg');
     background-size: cover;
     (...)
}
```

You may encounter some problems with your background-image when calling the URL parameter. To resolve this issue if you get in the way of it, go to this link:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/481

Answer (score 0):

That is because ion card has a default margin of 10px around it.

You can simply do so by overwriting the original CSS by providing your own styling for the `.card-md` class

```
.design  {
  background-image: url(.....);
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}

.card-md {
  margin: 0;
}
```

However, I would recommend you to set `background-position` as `center` instead.

```
.design  {
  background-image: url(...);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4daief?file=pages/home/home.scss).